# how can I rate and give review about doctor services?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, rating

I'm trying to give a rate and review for a doctor service and that rate will come from the patient which means I have two types of users so how could be the view

my models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)



class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    number_phone = models.CharField(
        _('االهاتف :'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)


class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="الاسم ")
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.user.username)


class Comments(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment')
    # co_email = models.ForeignKey(
    #     User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment')
    co_body = models.TextField(max_length=400, verbose_name='التعليق')
    rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    post = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'علق {} على {}'.format(self.created_by.username, self.post)
```

forms.py

```
class Commentair(forms.ModelForm):

    co_body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'rows': 3, 'placeholder': 'ما هو تعليقك عل الدكتور  ؟'}), label='التعليق')

    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ('co_body','rate')
```

html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                        <form action="" method="POST">

                                <div class="rate">
                                    <input type="radio" name="rate" id="rate10" value="5" required /><label
                                        for="rate10" title="5"></label>

                                    <input type="radio" name="rate" id="rate8" value="4" required /><label
                                        for="rate8" title="4"></label>

                                    <input type="radio" name="rate" id="rate6" value="3" required /><label
                                        for="rate6" title="3"></label>

                                    <input type="radio" name="rate" id="rate4" value="2" required /><label
                                        for="rate4" title="2"></label>

                                    <input type="radio" name="rate" id="rate2" value="1" required /><label
                                        for="rate2" title="1"></label>

                                </div>
                                <div class="review-body mt-2">
                                    <textarea name="co_body" rows="4" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Review" class="btn btn-primary">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>



 <div class="container mt-23">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-23">
                                <div dir="ltr">
                                    <div
                                        class="comment border bg-light border border-dark box-sizing-border-box p-4 rounded ">

                                        <div class="rating-star">
                                            <a class="text-cpitalize "><i class="fa fa-user   "></i>Rachid</a>
                                            <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur
                                                adipisicing Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                                                Animi, quo sapiente eaque consequatur nam, reprehenderit vitae
                                                distinctio soluta pariatur voluptas assumenda neque libero
                                                necessitatibus sit exercitationem possimus alias saepe vero.
                                            </p>
                                            <span class="jobs_right " style="margin-top: 10px;">

                                                <i class=" fa fa-star" style="float:right ;"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-star" style="float:right ;"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-star checked" style="float:right ;"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-star checked" style="float:right ;"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-star checked" style="float:right ;"></i>

                                                <p
                                                    class=" text-muted smallfont-weight-light position-absolute bottom-0 right-0 float-right ">
                                                    20/12/2022<i class="fa fa-clock-o mr-1"></i></p>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I'm wondering how could the view handles the stars rating and review . if there is any help please write it bellow and explain it please and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

models.py ( created and active blank=True, so you don't need to pass the values.)

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment')
    # co_email = models.ForeignKey(
    #     User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment')
    co_body = models.TextField(max_length=400, verbose_name='التعليق')
    rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)

    post = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'علق {} على {}'.format(self.created_by.username, self.post)
```

forms.py (Here we make our form for template. We have set 2 fields. "co_body" as textarea, "rate" as radio buttons and we pass our logged user direct to this form argument "user")

```
class Commentair(forms.ModelForm):
# This are choices what we present in our template.
# First is value which we pass to our model field which is integerfield.
# Second what should be presented in template. 
# I choose "Option 1-5" just to make clear for you.
    CHOICES = [
        (1, 'Option 1'),
        (2, 'Option 2'),
        (3, 'Option 3'),
        (4, 'Option 4'),
        (5, 'Option 5'),
    ]
    
    # First field Textarea
    co_body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'rows': 3, 'placeholder': 'ما هو تعليقك عل الدكتور  ؟'}), label='التعليق')

    # Second field radio buttons
    rate = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-radio'}) 
    # We pass css class form-radio so we can later in css style 
    # our radio buttons to be starts or something.

    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ('co_body','rate')
    
    # When initialization of our form occur we pass logged user.
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(Commentair, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # When save occur we save our passed user as created_by in model.
    def save(self, commit=True):
        inst = super(Commentair, self).save(commit=False)
        inst.created_by = self._user
        if commit:
            inst.save()
            self.save_m2m()
        return inst
```

views.py

```
def rate_page(request):
    
    # This block only happens when user have clicked submit button
    # in template
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Commentair(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # form is saved. 
            # return what ever you like (other page, message, etc.)

    # This is normal page render.
    form = Commentair(user=request.user)
    return render(request, tmpl_name, {'form': form}
```

template (we have passed our form object from view which contains both fields)

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Leave rating</button> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: what about the template what should I put in stars input and how I can get the data

Comment: In template {{ form }} in will render all fields including rating. To style it, here is great [tutorial] (https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-style-your-django-forms-7e8463aae4fa).

Comment: but there is stars  not only review .can you please show me how to deal with the template

Comment: I have edited code up. Added template and more comments for clarification.

Comment: that form will return  radio not stars so that's the problem

Comment: and if it's a way to turn it into stars can you please tell me how

Comment: [link](https://iamkate.com/code/star-rating-widget/) if something is not clear ask another question with css tag.